# Anaconda Python with Python 2.6

Tags: python, linux, installation, anaconda, python-2.6

I need to install [Anaconda Python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) on Linux but it has to be Python 2.6 (due to a package dependency). The computer doesn't have direct internet access although I can transfer files to it via another machine i.e. I can download X using another box and then transfer the file. This is how I have been pip installing packages

So my question is, how can I install Anaconda Python with Python 2.6 without direct internet access?

Maybe using an old Anaconda version but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anconda release notes has information about the version of Python they have shipped with some relese. For e.g in you can get Python 2.6.8 in Anaconda  1.7.0 release while Anaconda 1.8.0 had Python 2.6.9 . For more information please see https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/reference/release-notes/.

And for downloading the specific version of release use the following URL https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

Answer (score -2):

Anaconda provides an installer file, which is to say it provides a script file `anaconda-PYTHON_VERSION.sh` which can be downloaded on any machine for any version. You don't have to be on Linux to download the Linux Install file. Just like you don't need access to the internet on the machine you want to install Anaconda on.

Here's the link: [Python 3.5 and Python 2.7](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#linux)

You can directly use this for [64-bit Python 2.7 Install.sh](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh)

From the docs: `Anaconda supports Python 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5 only.`

Comment: It seems to me that this answer should begin with something like, "Anaconda Python 2.6 is not available, but..."

Comment: So it is not available for python 2.6. then?